# Evaluate $\int \frac{1}{\log^2(x)+\log(x)} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, indefinite-integrals

I am calculating the following integral:

$\int \frac{1}{\log^2(x)+\log(x)} dx$

Calculating this integral with the substitution method ($\log(x) = t$) I get

$x(\log^2(x)-\log(x)+1)+c$

but Wolfram says it is:

$\operatorname{li}(x) - \dfrac{Ei(\log(x)+1)}{e} + C$.

How would you solve this integral? Is the Wolfram's solution correct? There exists a simpler solution?

Kind regards,
Antonio

Comment: Please include steps by which you did the substitution you did.

Comment: partial fractions (on $\ln(x)$) & then look up $li$ & $Ei$.

Comment: Please, differentiate your result (which is not correct)

Comment: You appear to have integrated $\log^2x+\log x$.